# How to use Pinpoint send messages to specific devices using the Java AWS SDK for Pinpoint

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I have been able to get my mobile Android app to receive messages generated from the Pinpoint Campaign console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/home) to a specific device by targeting the segment to a custom attribute that only that device has.

Pinpoint Campaign config

- Mobile push channel
- Standard campaign
- Segment defined using custom attributes, holdout 0%
- Silent notification
- Custom JSON
- Launch immediate

Now I would like to implement this feature in my Java app using the SDK APIs and target the device's Pinpoint endpoint.

```
GetEndpointRequest getEndpointRequest = new GetEndpointRequest()
   .withApplicationId(appId)
   .withEndpointId(endpointId);
GetEndpointResult endpointResult = getAmazonPinpointClient().getEndpoint(getEndpointRequest);

DirectMessageConfiguration directMessageConfiguration =
  new DirectMessageConfiguration().withGCMMessage(new GCMMessage().withBody(body).withSilentPush(true).withAction(Action.OPEN_APP));
AddressConfiguration addressConfiguration = new AddressConfiguration().withChannelType(ChannelType.GCM);

MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest().withMessageConfiguration(directMessageConfiguration)
   .addAddressesEntry(endpointResponse.getAddress(), addressConfiguration);

SendMessagesRequest sendMessagesRequest = new SendMessagesRequest()
   .withApplicationId(appId)
   .withMessageRequest(messageRequest);
```

The "body" is the same JSON I put in the Pinpoint Campaign console.  When I run this, I get back a DeliveryStatus of SUCCESSFUL but the device never receives the message.

```
{ApplicationId: MY_APP_ID,Result: {clrVUcv-AwA:APA91bHGXkxpDJiw5kOMROA2XTJXuKreMklq9jemHO_KGYTIw6w84Fw9zLv9waMgLgha61IR-kZxgmrnFu-OGp8l6WFgp4Wolh4oOvZwMobGYNgzivv3bGIK83t-e4hiLx1TTaEIeRdQ={DeliveryStatus: SUCCESSFUL,StatusCode: 200,StatusMessage: {"multicast_id":4803589342422496921,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1515105369948916%c551fa42f9fd7ecd"}]},}}}
```

I have also tried this via the AWS CLI:

```
aws pinpoint send-messages --application-id MY_APP_ID --message-request "{\"Addresses\":{\"clrVUcv-AwA:APA91bHGXkxpDJiw5kOMROA2XTJXuKreMklq9jemHO_KGYTIw6w84Fw9zLv9waMgLgha61IR-kZxgmrnFu-OGp8l6WFgp4Wolh4oOvZwMobGYNgzivv3bGIK83t-e4hiLx1TTaEIeRdQ\":{\"ChannelType\":\"GCM\"}},\"MessageConfiguration\":{\"GCMMessage\":{\"Body\":\"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"stuff\\\"}\",\"SilentPush\":true}}}"
```

with a similar result (get 200 status code and DeliveryStatus of SUCCESSFUL but the app never receives).  I tried using the "Direct" message in the AWS Pinpoint console but they do not seem to support the same format (forces Action and Title/Message instead of silent push message with custom JSON).

Am I getting the endpoint incorrectly?  How do I translate the above campaign into a message?  I see there is a sendUserMessages() API call as well but that doesn't seem to be right one (I couldn't find where to specify the specific user endpoint)?

The client receives the campaign via the registered Service:

```
public class PushListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final String from, final Bundle data) {
    AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(this.getApplicationContext());
    final NotificationClient notificationClient = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient()
            .getPinpointManager().getNotificationClient();

    NotificationClient.CampaignPushResult pushResult =
            notificationClient.handleGCMCampaignPush(from, data, this.getClass());


    Log.e(LOG_TAG, " onMessageReceived - got messages"  + data);
```

Do GCM direct messages get sent through the same campaign method or do I have to register a different service to process these?

Comment: I was able to use the "Direct" message option in the AWS web console to target a message to the device using the endpoint ID, but I still haven't figured out how to translate this into the AWS CLI or AWS SDK for Pinpoint.

Comment: I managed to duplicate this with the AWS CLI using the following command:  
`aws pinpoint send-messages --application-id MY_APP_ID --message-request "{\"Context\":{},\"MessageConfiguration\":{\"DefaultMessage\":{\"Body\":\"Test from default message\",\"Substitutions\":{}},\"DefaultPushNotificationMessage\":{},\"APNSMessage\":{},\"GCMMessage\":{\"Data\":{\"message\":\"test\"},\"SilentPush\":true},\"BaiduMessage\":{},\"ADMMessage\":{},\"SMSMessage\":{}},\"Addresses\":{\"MY_ENDPOINT_ID\":{\"ChannelType\":\"GCM\"}},\"Endpoints\":{}}"`

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution based on the AWS CLI command I was able to run.  Should have been using the "Data" element and not the "Body" and need to enable "SilentPush".

```
EndpointResponse endpointResponse = getPinpointEndpointResponse(appId, pinpointEndpointId);

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
// construct data here, currently only supports Map<String, String>
// why not HashMap<String, Object> so it can support full JSON????

DirectMessageConfiguration directMessageConfiguration =
    new DirectMessageConfiguration().withGCMMessage(new GCMMessage().withData(data).withSilentPush(true));

AddressConfiguration addressConfiguration = new AddressConfiguration().withChannelType(ChannelType.GCM);

MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest().withMessageConfiguration(directMessageConfiguration)
    .addAddressesEntry(endpointResponse.getAddress(), addressConfiguration);

SendMessagesRequest sendMessagesRequest = new SendMessagesRequest()
    .withApplicationId(appId)
    .withMessageRequest(messageRequest);
```

Comment: Where did you get the documentation for this code?  Do you have a link you could share?

Comment: The documentation was sparse, I was trying to figure out how to configure it from the AWS Java SDK documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/AmazonPinpointClient.html and examples others had done (e.g., https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282165)